# Adding a second style to a div

Tags: css

I have two divs with the same style, but i'm trying to add another class to one of them in order to change the color, but it uses the default styling instead:

```
<div class="advertise-content create">

<p class="choose-header">hello!</p> <a href=""></a> </div>

<div class="advertise-content offer"> <p class="choose-header">hello!</p> <a href=""></a> </div>



.advertise-content{
height:230px;
flex-basis: 29.3%; 
margin-bottom:20px;
font-size: 1.3rem;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 5px solid #09eaf1;
align-items: center;
}

.offer{
border: 5px solid #0924f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first in the first class, you gave one style that's a different color, and then on other hand, you gave another style giving other color. Obviously, it will take the first one. To solve the problem either remove first-class from one div and add styling to its class.

```
<p class="choose-header">hello!</p> <a href=""></a> </div>

<div class="offer"> <p class="choose-header">hello!</p> <a href=""></a> </div>



.advertise-content{
height:230px;
flex-basis: 29.3%; 
margin-bottom:20px;
font-size: 1.3rem;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 5px solid #09eaf1;
align-items: center;
}

.offer{
height:230px;
flex-basis: 29.3%; 
margin-bottom:20px;
font-size: 1.3rem;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 5px solid #0924f1;
align-items: center;
}

 But I don't recommend this one. This may make your work even harder
Another method is to add `!important` like this `border: 5px solid #0924f1!important;`. This will surely solve your problem.
```

Comment: You used !important method?

Comment: No man, thank you, i'm new to webdev. It isn't easy figuring out stuff by myself

Answer (score -1):

You're missing '<' at the beginning of the first div.

Comment: It was just when I copy pasted, it`s not the issue